# Elasticsearch not showing any hits. Python Query is correct

Tags: python, elasticsearch, information-retrieval

First post.

I know this has been asked before but I emended my code based on previous solution but this still hasn't worked and that thread is closed, so I am creating a new one. Please bear with it.

I run the below code in python and no hits appear. I run the same query on kibana and I get all the results. Please let me know what did I do wrong here:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from datetime import datetime

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host": "localhost", "port": 9200}], connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, request_timeout=30)
doc = {'author': 'vaibhav','text': 'event',"timestamp": datetime.now()}
res = es.index(index="radius_ml_posts", id = 1, body = doc)
res = es.search(index="radius_ml_posts", size = 100, body={ "query": {
                                                            "query_string": { 
                                                            "default_field": "search_text",
                                                            "query": "thai food"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                )
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
res
Out[50]: 
{'took': 10,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': None,
  'hits': []}}
```

I know there is data and the query is correct, I can confirm on kibana.

Appreciate your inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Share the mapping of index and also share a sample doc which is expected to match the query.

Comment: You're searching on the filed `search_text` but the document you indexed doesn't have that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Turns out the index needed to be refreshed.

```
es.indices.refresh(index="my_index")
```

This did the trick.